# How to connect the markers on a graph using eventdd?

Tags: graph, continuous-integration

I'm working in a paper using event study methodology. For my graph I want to connect the markers and see the lines of the ci as the following example:

[Example of event study graph I want to generate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgutK.png)

To check how can I do it, I'm using the Stevenson and Wolfers (2006) divorce example:

`webuse set [www.damianclarke.net/stata/](http://www.damianclarke.net/stata/)
*(prefix now "http://www.damianclarke.net/stata")

webuse bacon_example.dta, clear

gen timeToTreat = year - _nfd

- Set scheme colors:
  grstyle init
  grstyle set lpattern dot  solid     /*patron de las dos lineas */
  grstyle set linewidth    medthick  thick /*Grosor de las dos lineas */
  grstyle set plain  , horizontal compact  minor dotted
  grstyle set color  "56 108 176"       "56 108 176"
  grstyle set symbol

#delimit
delimiter now
qui
eventdd asmrs pcinc asmrh cases i.year i.stfips, timevar(timeToTreat) ci(rline) cluster(stfips) graph_op(ytitle("Suicides per 1m Women") xlabel(-20(5)25) recast(line))`

The eventdd command produce the following graph:

[Adding recast(line) to eventdd command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn4BR.png)

The graph don't show the ci complete and don't connect the markers.

If I use the connect(direct) option produce the following graph:

[Show the ci lines no connect markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aApZV.png)

Now the graph shows the ci lines but don't connect the markers.

I read the manual of eventdd command and the syntaxis permit the ci and recast options. However, I don't know if the config of Stata change or I'm using a wrong option, but I can't produce the graph as the first.

I expect produce a graph as the example using the eventdd command.

Can you help me to fix it? Thanks.